# Set and display environment variable in power shell

Tags: powershell

I want to set NODE_OPTIONS as environment variable in powershell (windows 10)

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096
```

But I can't see the variable set, i.e.,

- `echo %NODE_OPTIONS%` -> give `%NODE_OPTIONS%`
- `echo $NODE_OPTIONS`
  -> give nothing

What's the right way to set and display environment variable in power shell?